# Apache2 PHP-FPM configuring pools

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, pool, fpm

I'm trying to set pools in order to run PHP scripts as different users, but it doesn't work.
Here's step by step what I did (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi php7.0-fpm php7.0

a2enmod actions fastcgi alias

sudo service apache2 restart

vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler php7-fcgi .php
  Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi virtual
  Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Then I created a user called "web"

```
sudo adduser web
```

and set up his home directory in /var/www/web

Create and configure the pool file for the new user:

```
sudo cp /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/web.conf

[web]
 ...
 user = web
 group = web
 ...
 listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.web.sock
 ...
 listen.owner = web
 listen.group = web

sudo service php7.0-fpm reload

vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/web.conf

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/web

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler php7-fcgi-web .php
  Action php7-fcgi-web /php7-fcgi-web virtual
  Alias /php7-fcgi-web /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-web
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-web -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.web.sock -pass-header Authorization
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</IfModule>

sudo a2ensite web.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Now to ensure php scripts run as the proper user I put the following script in /var/www and var/www/web

```
<?php
  $processUser = posix_getpwuid( posix_geteuid() );
  var_dump($processUser);
?>
```

when I run /var/www/user.php it displays "www-data" which is correct.
But when I run /var/www/web/user.php it still displays "www-data" whereas it should display "web"

So what's wrong with my Apache config ?